# How do I limit a query with distinct values in MariaDB

Tags: sql, mariadb

I have a table like this:

```
Id   Num   Some text
--------------------
1     1        ""
2     1        ""
3     2        ""
4     2        ""
5     2        ""
6     2        ""
7     3        ""
```

What I want is a query to select the first ten distinct nums, so if I want to get the two first nums I'll get the first six rows. I'm using MariaDB.

Comment: I'm not sure about mariadb, but in mssql I'd do it like this: select * from mytable where num in (select top 10 distinct num from mytable order by num)

Comment: I've tried with this query: select * from buses2 where numero in (select distinct numero from buses2 order by numero limit 1, 10), and I get this: #1235 - This version of MariaDB doesn't yet support 'LIMIT & IN/ALL/ANY/SOME subquery'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this approach:

```
select *
from Table1 as T1
join (
  select distinct num
  from Table1 
  order by num
  limit 2 ) as T2
on T1.num = T2.num  
  ;
```

In a fiddle here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1468ad/5

Comment: Your query returns nothing too, I don't know why

Comment: Well, as you can see, it works in the fiddle with the sample data you provided. When you say "it returns nothing" I assume you mean on your actual database? Then there is a difference which you have not included in the question.

Answer (score 0):

In MySQL you can use LIMIT. The caveat is that LIMIT is not directly supported in the `IN` sub-queries and therefore you must use a sub-query inside a IN sub-query:

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a307e/3)

**MySQL 5.6 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE Table1
    (`Id` int, `Num` int, `Some text` varchar(2))
;

INSERT INTO Table1
    (`Id`, `Num`, `Some text`)
VALUES
    (1, 1, '""'),
    (2, 1, '""'),
    (3, 2, '""'),
    (4, 2, '""'),
    (5, 2, '""'),
    (6, 2, '""'),
    (7, 3, '""')
;
```

**Query 1**:

```
select * from Table1
where Num in (select Num FROM(select distinct Num from Table1 order by Num limit 2)a)
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a307e/3/0)**:

```
| Id | Num | Some text |
|----|-----|-----------|
|  1 |   1 |        "" |
|  2 |   1 |        "" |
|  3 |   2 |        "" |
|  4 |   2 |        "" |
|  5 |   2 |        "" |
|  6 |   2 |        "" |
```

Comment: do you need an `ORDER BY` in there?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I have added the order by

Comment: I have tried something similar a week ago but MariaDB doesn't implements IN clause. But using your query, it returns nothing :S

Comment: MariaDB _does_ implement `IN`.  But the query is better done with `JOIN`.